# Self-adjointness of $X^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a vector field on a compact (may be even complete) Riemannian manifold without boundary. I am wondering if $X^2$ will be a self-adjoint operator on $L^2(M)$. Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you more explain about $X^2$ ?